# How to fetch records in between the ranges of two columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, between

Here is the following table I've i.e **machine_shifts**

```
CREATE TABLE `machine_shifts` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `shift_start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `shift_end_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `shift` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`shift`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data is

```
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-01','00:00:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-01','06:00:00','13:00:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-01','13:00:00','24:00:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-02','00:00:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-02','06:00:00','13:00:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-02','13:00:00','24:00:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-03','00:00:00','06:00:00','C','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-03','06:00:00','13:00:00','A','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
insert into `machine_shifts` (`date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_time`, `shift`, `updated_on`) values('2010-01-03','13:00:00','24:00:00','B','2020-01-29 15:37:26');
```

[image: Kishore Kumar Korada]

And let's say I've a machine that started on **2010:01:01** at time **07:01:00** and ended on **2010:01:03** at time **10:00:00**.

I want to query the above table to get the records between the date with start time and the date with end time.

*Expected output:*

[image]

In between the marking line is the expected output.

Comment: And what would be the output?

Comment: @juergend edited the question and mentioned the expected output.

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada Still question is not clear enough.

Comment: @ArifulIslam I've edited my question. Could you please check it, if you are able to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM machine_shifts
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_start_time),'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s' )
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-01 07:01:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s') 
       AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-03 10:00:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s'))
AND   (STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_end_time),'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s' )
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-01 07:01:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s') 
       AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-03 10:00:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s'));
```

Additional info:

- `%Y` = Year(4 digits)
- `%c` = month (0-12)
- `%e` = Day of the month (0-31)
- `%H` = Hour (00 to 23)
- `%i` = Minutes (00 to 59)
- `%s` = Seconds (00 to 59)

Or if you wish that results if any of the conditions aer satisfied then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM machine_shifts
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_start_time),'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s' )
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-01 07:01:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s') 
       AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-03 10:00:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s'))
OR   (STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_end_time),'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s' )
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-01 07:01:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s') 
       AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-03 10:00:00', '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s'));
```

OR version without extra STR_TO_DATE:

```
SELECT *
FROM machine_shifts
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_start_time),'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s' )
       BETWEEN '2010-01-01 07:01:00' AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00')
OR   (STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_end_time),'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s' )
       BETWEEN '2010-01-01 07:01:00' AND '2010-01-03 10:00:00');
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the definition of the table

Comment: Hi @KishoreKumarKorada nice! This should then work. Have you tried it ? What is the problem ? I have updated my query to fit your data requirements... Column date has only year-month-day and shift_start_time has time part...

Comment: Hi @KishoreKumarKorada  please check the new query. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @VBoka, Thank you for your effort. Have you seen the mentioned output? If that makes sense to you, then your query isn't returning the same results. When the shift started at  07:01:00 on 2010-01-01, that means it should display 2010-01-01 with A and B shift data too. Your query is returning results from 2010-01-02. Shell I give you the table data?

Comment: Please can you confirm you have tried the new code ? Edited 15 min ago ? Thanks! Also please can you tell me why does the first row in your "Expected output:" enters the expected output ? Shift started at 06:00:00

Comment: Yes I've tried.
Also I've just edited the question to put insert queries with the data for specified dates.

Comment: Yes. First row should be Shift Started at 06:00:00 2010-01-01

Comment: Ok, but why ? Please explain that first row. It is in expected result because....Thanks

Comment: I understand I think. Try the new query.

Comment: Shift started 07:01:00 on 2010:01:01. And that falls under shift 06:00:00 and 13:00:00 i.e A Shift. And I need that row so that can make some operations.
Let's say if that have that row, then I would know later from what time machine was in that shift. i.e from 07AM to 1PM(Shift end time). Let me know still you want any more clarifications. I'm ready to give.

Comment: Hi @KishoreKumarKorada, thanks, no need, I have updated my query.

Comment: Happy Programming :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM machine_shifts
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_start_time),'%Y-%e-%c %H:%i:%s' ) >= '2010-01-01 07:01:00' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(concat(date, ' ', shift_end_time),'%Y-%e-%c %H:%i:%s' ) <= '2010-01-03 10:00:00';
```

And one suggestion you can implement - use `DATETIME` field rather `TIME` on both `shift_start_time` and `shift_end_time` and remove `date` column. This will make your query more easy and more faster.

Comment: It's not working. As you can see, shift_start_time and shift_end_time are part of the date. Your query just returning empty result set.

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada Please check now.

Comment: This uses the same logic to concatenate and convert date column and time column as my answer and also if the data is not ok(for example start date is 2010:01:04 00:00:01 and enda date is 2010-01-01 00:00:00) this will return this row...

Answer (score 0):

select * from machine_shifts where date between 2010-01-01 and 2010-01-03 and shift_start_time >= start_time and shift_end_time <= end_time

Comment: FYI. There is a dependancy on shift time.